# How can i transfer my whatsapp chat history to my new phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am using whatsapp on Samsung ace. Now I want to use whatsapp in my new HTC one. How can I transfer my my all chat histories from old phone to new phone?

Comment: This question already has been asked here multiple times. Please take a look at: [Transfer Whatsapp chat history to new device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74973/16575) / [How to transfer WhatsApp conversations to a new phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/62237/16575)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open WhatsApp
2. Press menu button
3. Press settings
4. Press Chat settings
5. Press Backup conversations
6. Close WhatsApp
7. Connect phone to computer
8. Open Explorer and navigate to your phone's internal memory
9. Find WhatsApp folder, copy it
10. Paste to your computer
11. Disconnect old phone, connect new phone to your computer
12. Copy WhatsApp folder from your computer
13. Paste WhatsApp folder to your internal memory of your new phone
14. Install WhatsApp on your new phone
15. Follow the instructions in WhatsApp
16. After registring your phone number WhatsApp should recognize your WhatsApp backup and automatically import your old conversations, contacts and media

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if you _haven't_ already transferred service over to your new phone.  If you transfer service, WhatsApp will lock itself on your old phone, and the menu will not have any options except 'Contact Support'.  Are there instructions that work when the new phone has already been activated?

Comment: In Step 13, Can't I copy the WhatsApp folder to external SD card of my new phone