# How to take whatsapp backup (from Phone Memory to Sd Card) on Android

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.1-jelly-bean, backup, whatsapp-messenger

I am using Whatsapp on my android phone. Since the phone as Jellybean installed, it doesn't have "Move to SD Card" feature and hence all my whatsapp files such as Backup, Media etc were stored in Phone, which eventually consumes lot of space on the phone.

Since I would now be purchasing new phone (which has KitKat version), I would like to know how can I take backup of whatsapp so that the images taken within the backup are stored in SD card in new phone.

Please assist me.

P.S.: I know how to take a manual backup of Whatsapp on an Android Phone.

Comment: I've done that successfully following the steps described in [How can i transfer my whatsapp chat history to my new phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75260/16575). Note that WA always uses the internal SD if available. For the "official variant", also take a look at [Transfer Whatsapp chat history to new device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74973/16575).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to copy the `WhatsApp` folder from your internal sd card (`/sdcard`) to your new phone. If you then first launch WhatsApp it should ask if it should restore your messages.

Note: This only works if you use the same phone number on both devices. For more information about that see the WhatsApp FAQ: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921

Comment: Yes I will be using same number.
So I have to copy the entire WhatsApp folder from internal SD card of old phone to external SD card of new phone?

Comment: Not the external SD card but the internal SD card of the new phone. Implied that WhatsApp's FAQ is correct it should ask you to restore all your messages. Just in case I would do a full backup of the WhatsApp data inside `/data/com.whatsapp/` as well.

Comment: How to make sure that the whatsapp folder is stored in external sd card? I did the same thing (as suggested by you in your post) for my friend and whatsapp automatically stored the contents in External SD card.

Comment: I think you are mismatching `/sdcard` and `/external_sd`. `/sdcard` is your internal storage so you have to copy your files to `/external_sd` to back them up to your sd card.

Comment: I understood that /sdcard is internal storage (aka Phone storage). So you mean that I have to manually copy the whatsapp folder to Micro SD Card (External)?

Comment: Yes and then on the new phone you have to copy it back to the internal storage before launching WhatsApp for the first time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19759/discussion-between-romil-n-and-gianttree).

Answer (score 2):

On the latest version of Whatsapp you can easily backup WhatsApp conversations with Google Drive. Google Drive is a online file storage service which provided by Google. If you have a Google account you can easily backup and restore whatsapp messages whenever you want.

Read more at [Techofy](http://www.techofy.org/2015/04/how-to-backup-whatsapp-messages.html).