# whats app messenger

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Hi I have just bought another android phone, but I really want to see the old messages.  When I purchase my new phone, I had to obtain a nano sim, I managed to keep my old number for the new phone (still have the old phone with another sim in it).  On the old phone I can still see old messages, but as soon as I go to look at old messages and pictures, Whats app thinks I have/want two accounts and then blocks the new phone.  I just want to be able to see all my old messages on my new phone, what can I do.  Also, I am not the most technical person going, but help would be fantastic please.  My messages mean a lot to me.  Thank you.

Comment: Please see: [Transfer Whatsapp chat history to new device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74973/16575) / [How to transfer WhatsApp conversations to a new phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/62237/16575)

Answer (score 0):

In the new phone do a "clear data"  for the whatsapp,  then copy the whatsapp folder from the old phone to the new one. Now try to open the whatsapp and activate it on your number. It will ask you weather you want to import the existing history or not.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply, how do you do a 'clear data' for Whatsapp?

Comment: Setting >> Application Manager >> Whatsapp >> Clear Data