# Last 10 days missing after I transferred WhatsApp messages to new phone

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore

I've tried to transfer all my Whatsapp messages from an old Android phone to a new Android phone. I followed all the instructions at [Whatsapp's website](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/20902622) and [previously on Stackoverflow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62237/how-to-transfer-whatsapp-conversations-to-a-new-phone), but am missing the last 10 days of messages in my phone. I've redone the process twice, but have had no luck.

Interestingly, the backups on my old phone grow larger for the first 4 days of backups, but then get smaller in the last two days. But this might just be because they changed from .crypt7 files in the first four days to .crypt8 files for the last two days.

Are there tools available to import specific .crypt* files, or to merge archived backups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first couple times I had tried to .zip the folder, share it on Google Drive, and unzip it on the new phone and import it. I finally got it to work by copying the folder through the SD Card and transferring the SD card between phones. Not sure if it was dumb luck or if something was corrupted in the zipping process!

Answer (score 5):

I have just got this very same problem here and got it solved. Here is how I did it:

I got my previous phone that still had all messages on it and did a new backup on WhatsApp settings. Unistall WhatsApp on your new phone and remove the WhatsApp folder from it. After that, copy the whole WhatsApp folder to SD card and transferred to the new phone.

Here comes the difference: I deleted all the last backups from the copy I just made and left only the last one. Now I have only these two files on the database folder: msgstore-2014-12-26.1.db.crypt8 and msgstore.db.crypt8

Now copy the folder back to internal memory and install WhatsApp again.

To simplify: I just deleted the previous backups and kept the last one I just made and made the default message restoration process again

Answer (score 1):

For those of you, who the other answers does not work for, here is how it worked for me:

In addition to deleting the older message.db.crypt files as described by Arthur, I also deleted the latest "date" file so that only one file (message.db.crypt8) was left.

Having those files in the sdcard/WhatsApp folder I (re)installed WhatsApp. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what worked for me, leaving a backup "confused" Whatsapp